# Setup macOS13 Ventura with Apple M2 chip - Unable to install header files for compiling C extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sudo, apple-m1, macos-ventura, gobject-introspection

While setting up a new laptop, macOS 13 Ventura, Apple M2 chip, for RoR.

The directions recommend running the following command:

sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /

The command failed with the error:

"installer: Error - the package path specified was invalid"

I have also tried to install the following gems:

rsvg2,
glib2,
gobject-introspection

which failed to build the native extensions.

Could the two issues be related?

Comment: Originally we were using Ruby 3.1.3. Once we reverted back to 2.7.7 the gems did install.